# "FAT-fs: IO charset iso8859-1 not found" error while mounting FAT Drives

Tags: mount, fat32

I am unable to mount ***any*** `fat32` or `fat16` formatted usb disks under Ubuntu 13.10.
The thing here to note is that it is happening only with `fat` formatted Disks. `ntfs`, `ext` formatted external usb disks work well 
(I tried formatting the same with `ext4` and it worked)

While mounting via `nautilus`:

[image: Error while mounting via File Manager]

Error while mounting from terminal:

```
root@shubham-pc:~# mount -t vfat /dev/sdc1 /media/shubham/n
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdc1,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so
```

As suggested by the error: 
Output from `dmesg | tail`

```
root@shubham-pc:~# dmesg | tail
[ 3545.482598] scsi8 : usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 3546.481530] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SanDisk  Cruzer           1.26 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[ 3546.482373] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[ 3546.483758] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 15633408 512-byte logical blocks: (8.00 GB/7.45 GiB)
[ 3546.485254] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[ 3546.485262] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[ 3546.488314] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[ 3546.499820]  sdc: sdc1
[ 3546.503388] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3547.273396] FAT-fs (sdc1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found
```

Output from `fsck.vfat`:

```
root@shubham-pc:~# fsck.vfat /dev/sdc1
dosfsck 3.0.16, 01 Mar 2013, FAT32, LFN
/dev/sdc1: 1 files, 1/1949978 clusters
```

All normal

Tried re-creating the whole partition table and then formatting as `fat32` but to no avail so the possibility of corrupted drive is ruled out.
Tried the same with around 4 Disks or so and all have the same things

Comment: Do you use a self-compiled kernel or default Ubuntu one?

Comment: The default one

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, your kernel somehow has problems (maybe a bug). Since there is an updated version available, install it (version `3.11.0-13-generic`)

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

now reboot in your new kernel.

Comment: i have linux 3.16 and have same problem.

Comment: I have Linux kernel 4.4.0-53 and I have the same problem. apt-get reports "linux-generic is already the newest version".

Comment: @larskholte either you have a mis-configured system or you've hit a bug in the kernel/module. Either way, my answer given the information available is correct, your case might be different unless you are using 3.11 kernel.

Comment: removed the latest kernel image and worked like a charm. but don't have any idea what to do when the update comes back again

Comment: @benjaminbutton report the bug with all the debugging information you can provide. Otherwise, how you expect it to be fixed?

Comment: @Braiam I believe I didn't mention about "fixing" it. I told, "I don't have any idea how to prevent to upgrade to this kernel version".  And also how do you know that I haven't submitted a bug report? Why are you people so mad and inconsiderate nowadays? ...

Comment: @benjaminbutton if you are worried about when the "update comes back again" it very likely means that you don't actually expect it to be fixed in the next version, and the most likely reason why you would have those expectations is because you haven't initiated the process of fixing it, which is done by bug reporting; otherwise it's very likely your wording would be more positive.

Comment: Do a `fsck -f <device>`, if you get a lot of inode repair actions, you know that your disk is corrupted and your inodes are broken.... You need to do a reinstall ;(

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem a few days ago with 4.4.0-57. `modprobe nls_iso8859-1` threw an error, and without that module, that "IO charset not found" message appears.

Turns out the root filesystem was damaged.
After a thorough fsck and reinstalling of the kernel (forced with `apt-get install --reinstall`), that module loads again, and I can mount my USB sticks.

@larskholte Even if the update to 4.4.0-57 fixed your problem by replacing the bad module, be sure to fsck your filesystems! That module not loading is only a symptom of a much bigger problem.

Comment: I think you are correct. I think the root cause might indeed be a broken filesystem. In my case it doesn't load modules anymore either, I don't even get networking to work. Maybe my nvme disk died!?

Comment: Can I maybe ask how did you confirm your filesystem was damaged? Since fsck doesn't complain here.

Comment: (trying to load an older kernel didn't work either btw, so it make sense that maybe my whole fs is corrupt)

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg I noticed errors in dmesg, then fsck -f compained a lot, but at least left a usable filesystem. What fsck doesn't fix is corrupt file contents, thus the --reinstall.

Comment: But if you keep having problems after a kernel downgrade, the kernel modules obviously can't be the problem. Maybe try to reinstall modprobe? What kind of error do you get anyway?
And what does smartctl / nvme-cli have to say about your nvme stick? Running memtest86(+) also is a good idea when facing weird problems.

Comment: Yea so memtest is now running fine. Smart is saying all disks are fine. Fsck without `-f` went fine, with the `-f` option it gives indeed strange inode issues. https://i.ibb.co/f2GS1wR/strange.png. Still unsure why the data got corrupted after a simple restart. Since the disk health (smart) is all fine, I will go for a reinstall.