# System does not detect USB pendrives

Tags: usb

This USB thing is driving me crazy. 2 problems in time span of 3 hours.
Ok I was already trying to cope up with ["FAT-fs (sdc1): IO charset iso8859-1 not found" error while mounting FAT Drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372445/wrong-fs-type-bad-option-bad-superblock-error-while-mounting-fat-drives/372462) when to my amazement I discovered that none of the USB Storage devices showed up in the system

Useful outputs:
- `tail /var/log/syslog`:

```
root@shubham-pc:~# tail  /var/log/syslog
Nov  7 21:41:47 shubham-pc colord: device removed: sysfs-HP-v250w
Nov  7 21:41:51 shubham-pc kernel: [ 3441.529542] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 11
Nov  7 21:41:53 shubham-pc kernel: [ 3443.820029] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci-pci
Nov  7 21:41:54 shubham-pc kernel: [ 3443.952897] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5530
Nov  7 21:41:54 shubham-pc kernel: [ 3443.952905] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Nov  7 21:41:54 shubham-pc kernel: [ 3443.952909] usb 1-2: Product: Cruzer
Nov  7 21:41:54 shubham-pc kernel: [ 3443.952913] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Nov  7 21:41:54 shubham-pc kernel: [ 3443.952917] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 20060876420EC6016847
Nov  7 21:41:54 shubham-pc mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 14: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-2"
Nov  7 21:41:54 shubham-pc mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 14 was not an MTP device
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the kernel somehow had problems (maybe a bug). Since there was an updated version,  I installed it:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

now reboot in your new kernel.